# Pandas apply function alternatives for pyspark dataframe (want to convert integer data type column to list data type)

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Want to convert integer datatype column to list datatype

Given DataFrame

```
   a  b
0  9  2
1  9  3
```

Want to convert to

```
   a    b
0  9  [2]
1  9  [3]
```

Pandas solution

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2],"b":[3,4]})
df["b"] = df["b"].apply(lambda row: [row])
```

How can I achieve the same in pyspark ?

I tried a naive way

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df_sp = spark.createDataFrame(df)
#EDIT according to 过过招 Answer 
df_sp = df_sp.withColumn("b",col("b").cast(ArrayType(IntegerType())))
display(df_sp)
```

Which gives an error  `AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`b`' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast bigint to array<int>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the data type of `element` in the `array`.

```
df_sp = df_sp.withColumn("b", col("b").cast(ArrayType(IntegerType())))
df_sp.show()
```

Comment: Thanks the old error "TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'elementType'" is gone but this gives a new error "AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`b`' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast bigint to array<int>;"  How can i convert Integer to Array ?

Comment: Please print the schema and post the result before executing the cast.```df_sp.printSchema()```

Comment: Or try: ```df_sp = df_sp.withColumn("b", col("b").cast(ArrayType(LongType())))```.Don't forget to import ```LongType``` first.

Comment: the above gives this error "
AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`b`' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast bigint to array<bigint>;"

I guess the issue is we can't use a cast command to convert an integer to an Array

Comment: What version of your spark is?

Comment: I am using spark 3.1.1 version

Comment: Since ```b``` is ```bigint``` type, then try to use the ```array``` function to convert to array type.```import pyspark.sql.functions as F   df_sp = df_sp.withColumn('b', F.array('b'))```